# default config not recognised in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

On updating to Android studio 3.1, i am getting this error

The SourceSet 'defaultConfig' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin. Perhaps you misspelled something?

build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
}


apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    //buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
//    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mpathway.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
    }
    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
//        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i am getting warning on compile even though i removed and error on defaultconfig

Can someone help me out with this issue?and let me know what to replace it with
Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]. This would include the `build.gradle` file that is giving you this error.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare i 've updated the post thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple `defaultConfig` closures. Ideally, there would only be one.

Regardless, `defaultConfig` goes directly inside of the `android` closure, not inside of the `sourceSets` closure.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, it worked but, do you know why i still get the compile warning even though i changed compile to implementation ?

Comment: @koushikv: I am not certain what you are referring to. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve] showing the error and showing the file that is triggering the error.

Comment: i meant the same gradle file ....i am still getting a warning as     "Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018"                                         even though i changed compile to implementation